# How can I use throttling with getting an event target?

Tags: javascript, events, ecmascript-6, throttling

By referring to this site,
https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-646d076d0a44

```
throttled(delay, fn) {
    let lastCall = 0;
    return function (...args) {
        const now = (new Date).getTime();
        if (now - lastCall < delay) {
            return;
        }
        lastCall = now;
        return fn(...args);
    }
}
```

I want use throttled function like this.

```
item.addEventListener('click', throttled(2000, func(e.target)));
```

I have to use this to get the value of e.target.
However, if you write this code, the throttled function will not work properly.

```
item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {throttled(2000, func(e.target))});
```

How can I get the throttled function to work properly while getting targeted click events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `throttled` function will return a wrapper function around your original event handler. It will pass whatever arguments it received when `now - lastCall >= delay` to the `fn` callback function.
This is this wrapper function that you will add as an event handler, i.e the return value of `throttled()`.

So all you need to pass to `throttled` is a normal event handler, i.e the same you would have passed to the event listener:

```js
// let's be a bit verbose

// our event handler
function handleevent(evt) {
  console.log(evt.clientX); // logging the clientX here because evt.target is a big object for SO's console.
}
// the wrapper function
const myThrottledFunc = throttled(2000, handleevent);
// we add the wrapper as event handler
addEventListener('click', myThrottledFunc);


function throttled(delay, fn) {
  let lastCall = 0;
  return function wrapper(...args) {
    const now = (new Date).getTime();
    if (now - lastCall < delay) {
      return;
    }
    lastCall = now;
    return fn(...args);
  }
}
```

```html
click anywhere
```

Or as one-liner `onclick = throttled(2000, evt => console.log(evt.target));`

Comment: Hi can you please explain or refer to some documentation why `function throttled(delay, fn) {
  let lastCall = 0;`
doesn't reinit `lastCall to 0` That's quite amazing

Comment: @BlackMamba It does, but `throttled` is called only once the first time we initialize the wrapper function. What gets called multiple time is the wrapper, but this one never sets lastCall to 0.

Comment: Oh ok I got that now

Answer (score 1):

Your throttled function expects a function as a second parameter.

let's assume func simply logs `e.target` to the console, you could write:

```
item.addEventListener('click', throttled(2000, func));
```

with

```
const func = (e) => console.log(e.target);
```

Or if you want everything in one line:

```
item.addEventListener('click', throttled(2000, (e) => func(e.target)));
```